# Principal ideal domain - polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, principal-ideal-domains

Let $f(x)=x^2+3x+5,\ \  g(x)=x+1\in\mathbb{R}[x]$. Show that $1\in f(x)\mathbb{R}[x]+g(x)\mathbb{R}[x]$ and hence that $f(x)\mathbb{R}[x]+g(x)\mathbb{R}[x]=\mathbb{R}[x]$.

My idea is to use the division algorithm to get $x^2+3x+5=(x+1)(x+2)+3$, so $f(x)=(x+2)g(x)+3$. Hence $f(x)\mathbb{R}[x]+g(x)\mathbb{R}[x]=(x+2)g(x)\mathbb{R}[x]+g(x)\mathbb{R}[x]=g(x)\mathbb{R}[x](x+3)$ (I'm not sure this is allowed).

How do we show $1$ is an element of this and how do we then deduce the required result?

Comment: You just need to find two polynomials $p(x), q(x)$ such that $p(x) f(x) + q(x) g(x) = 1$. If that's the case, then $1$ is in the ideal.

Comment: Have you heard of the Bezout identity?

Comment: @DogeChan How can we do that easily?

Comment: @MichaelMorrow I have indeed but I'm not sure how to apply it here. Is it enough to say that one doesn't divide the other so their gcd is $1$ and using Bezout there are such polynomials $p,q$?

Comment: @turtle111 A left ideal is an additive subgroup of a ring. So if a left ideal $I$ in $R$ is generated by $p,q$ for instance, then $rp+sq$ is in the ideal for all $r,s\in R$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Your work shows that $3\in f(x)\mathbb{R}[x]+g(x)\mathbb{R}[x]$, since rearranging yields
$$
3=1\cdot(x^2+3x+5)+(-(x+2))\cdot(x+1)=1\cdot f(x)+(-(x+2))\cdot g(x)
$$
and clearly $1,-(x+2)\in\mathbb{R}[x]$.

Now, note that your coefficients are allowed to come from $\mathbb{R}$, not just $\mathbb{N}$ -- how could you modify the polynomials above (that is, $1$ and $-(x+2)$) to get $1$ as a result?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand...

Comment: Then ask a question -- help me help you!

Comment: I agree that what I've written shows that $3$ is in the set, and your hint suggests to me that we can write something like $1=\frac{1}{3}\times (x^2+3x+5)+\frac{1}{3}(-(x+2))\times(x+1)=\frac{1}{3}f(x)-\frac{1}{3}(-x-2)g(x)$. But I'm not fully sure...

Comment: Right, so that shows that $1\in f(x)\mathbb{R}[x]+g(x)\mathbb{R}[x]$.  But then you can show that any polynomial in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is in the set as well -- just multiply the coefficients by it!

Comment: So more formally we could say something like if $p(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x]$ then $p(x)\times 1=\frac{1}{3}\times p(x)\times f(x)+\frac{1}{3}p(x)(x+2)\times g(x)$?

Comment: Yep.  And since $\frac{1}{3}p(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x]$ and $\frac{1}{3}p(x)(x+2)\in\mathbb{R}[x]$, that tells you that $p(x)\in f(x)\mathbb{R}[x]+g(x)\mathbb{R}[x]$.